# GetCharacterRect sometimes gives wrong rect

Tags: wpf

I have a `UserControl` that has a `FlowDocument` on it.
when I create an object of it, I add load event and after that I add it to a `StackPanel`.

```
   ViewCell cell = new ViewCell(); 
   cell.Loaded += Cell_Loaded;
   sp_Texts.Children.Add(cell);
            
   private void Cell_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        foreach (var item in sp_Texts.Children)
          {          
               double y = (item as ViewCell).GetYPosition();
               ...
               return;
          }
   }
```

In Cell_Loaded I want to know rect of some words in FlowDocument in ViewCell. sometimes it gives me correct answer, but sometimes it gives me infinity because textpointer has not a valid layout.

```
    public double GetYPosition()
    {
        TextPointer startpos;
        ...
        var verticalScrollPos = startPos.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward).Y;
        return verticalScrollPos ;
     }
```

Comment: As a note, you shouldn't be writing something like `(item as ViewCell).GetYPosition()`. When you use the `as` operator, check the result for null. Otherwise use a type cast: `((ViewCell)item).GetYPosition()`

Comment: Even better: `foreach (var viewCell in sp_Texts.Children.OfType<ViewCell>())`

Comment: yes, you're right, thank you, any solution?